# Remove Firebase Node with Specific Child Value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have below firebase database structure.I need to delete the whole key having specific `dMoble` value

[image]

I have tried below code but its not working

```
 String emailID= singleToneClass.getInstance().getData();

 mDataBase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
 mReferenceBooks=mDataBase.getReference("books");                       

 mReferenceBooks.orderByChild("dMoble").equalTo(emailID)
 .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    mReferenceBooks.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).removeValue();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
@Override 
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     mReferenceBooks.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).removeValue();
     }
```

Into this:

```
@Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
mReferenceBooks.child(ds.getKey()).removeValue();
   }
```

Your reference is at node `books`, to access the `key` you need to iterate inside of it and then use `getKey()`